# Display Modal If condition is true in Angular?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I want to display the modal once the ticket is successfully generated only.
When the user click the button "mybutton" it will open the modal only if there is no error.

**ticket.components.ts**

```
constructor(private _service: TicketService, private _idservice: SharedService) {
   }

generateTicket(){
    this._idservice.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.userId = message)
    this._service.createTicketFromRemote(this.ticket, this.userId).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log("response recieved");
        this.msg = "Ticket Successfully Generated";

        // code to display modal

      },
      error => {
        this.open_Modal = false;
        console.log("exception occured");
        console.log(error);

        // do nothing
      }
    )

  }
```

**ticket.component.html**

```
<button name="myButton" (click)="generateTicket()" class="btn btn-primary">Generate Ticket</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal Title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"> 
        <p class="text-center">Modal Body</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer"> 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Print</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  data-dismiss="modal" >Edit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use this line to open the modal from your .ts file

```
 $('#exampleModalLong').modal('show');
```

Also dont forget to declare the dollar sign '$', use this line just after your imports in the .ts file

```
declare var $: any;
```

Comment: @DishaHedge thanks your solution works but can you tell me why the above two solution don't work

Comment: My solution works, Jacopo Sciampi one not because of modal css class. To use jquery in angular2+ is not best practice. In some cases is wrong!

Answer (score 2):

The class modal has css property dispaly:none so you have to add dispaly: block property to show the modal.

Html

Add **ngClass** directive to conditionally add o remove showModal css class

```
div class="modal fade" [ngClass]="{'showModal': openModal}" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    .......
</div>
```

In ts.

```
generateTicket(){
    this._idservice.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.userId = message)
    this._service.createTicketFromRemote(this.ticket, this.userId).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log("response recieved");
        this.msg = "Ticket Successfully Generated";

        this.openModal = true; // <------ Like Jacopo Sciampi said

      },
```

For close the modal.

```
closeModal() {
   this.openModal = false;
  }
```

css

```
.showModal {
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: no I think I have done some thing wrong in my code. I will try to debug my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `ngIf` to achieve this:

```
generateTicket(){
    this._idservice.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.userId = message)
    this._service.createTicketFromRemote(this.ticket, this.userId).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log("response recieved");
        this.msg = "Ticket Successfully Generated";

        this.open_Modal = true; // <------

      },
      error => {
        this.open_Modal = false;
        console.log("exception occured");
        console.log(error);

        // do nothing
      }
    )

  }
```

in the html, add the ngIf to the main modal div:

```
<div *ngIf="open_Modal" class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal Title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"> 
        <p class="text-center">Modal Body</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer"> 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Print</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  data-dismiss="modal" >Edit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also wrap the main div into a `ng-container` with the ngIf there, instead of in the div, to make the code more clean:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="open_Modal">
<div  class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal Title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body"> 
            <p class="text-center">Modal Body</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer"> 
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Print</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  data-dismiss="modal" >Edit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```